# Find the module and argument of the complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Please find the argument and module of $\frac {2-i}{-\sqrt{3}-2i}$ ?

I have tried 
This is correct or wrong

1. $\frac {2-i}{-\sqrt{3}-2i}$
2. $\frac {({2-i)}× {(-\sqrt{3}+2i)}}{ {(-\sqrt{3}-2i)}× {(-\sqrt{3}+2i)}} $
3. $\frac {(-2\sqrt{3}+2)+(4+\sqrt{3})i}{3+4}$
4. $\frac{(-2\sqrt{3}+2)}{7}+\frac {(4+\sqrt{3})i}{7}$

Please check my steps.

Comment: I think looks good

Comment: @AsamHussain  your answer is correct.

Comment: ^ Did either of you two read the title / first sentence?

Comment: Can u find the argument

Comment: @epimorphic. Yes, and this post is a continuation from a different post. It is part of an earlier process

Comment: @AsamHussain. Argument is the arctan of $b$ over $a$, so take out paper and pencil to divide your imaginary component by the real component.

Comment: If you're only asked for the modulus and argument, just find those of the "numerator" and "denominator" and divide (for modulus) and subtract (for argument) respectively. It saves so much work.

Comment: Please so the step

Comment: @AsamHussain. Deepak is referring to a different approach. Are you familiar with DeMoivre? Then that is what Deepak is referring to. If not, then your approach is the way.

Comment: Anyone can u answer please